# Static classes and "this" keyword

Tags: windows, forms, static

I have a static class with a custom event in it, as below:

```
    //The delegate
    public static delegate void eventDoneDelegate(object sender, WebLoaderEventArgs e);

    //The event that uses the delegate
    public static event eventDoneDelegate PageRequestDone;

    //Calls the event
    private static void onPageRequestDoneChanged(WebLoaderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PageRequestDone != null)
            PageRequestDone(this, e);
    }
```

I know "this" can't be used because it references the current instance, but how can I pass the currect class as a parameter?

Or maybe my logic is wrong, please aware me as I am new to this.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear what's going on here. Why are all of these static in the first place? What do you even mean by "this" if you've got a static class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantic meaning of the `sender` argument value depends on a vague agreement between the event publisher and the event subscribers; there is no universal standard. In your example, I can't see any need for a sender value at all, you might as well pass null.

Comment: Why didn't I think of this ealier? Ofc... no need to pass a sender reference, because there is only one sender possible. Thanks mate.